# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( while running JS function

Tags: javascript, html

While debugging an issue I executed the following in console of chrome browser

```
function(){ console.log('hi') }
```

I am getting following error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

Could you please explain why is it returning error? It should print the value 'hi'.
Thanks

Comment: I'm getting a different error. Also, the above will not print "hi", it will try and define an anonymous function. To display hi, paste `console.log('hi')`

Comment: Hi Chris,
I understand that if i use console.log('hi') ,I will get hi printed on the screen but i was using data bind on a button and in that i have to use function on the click of a button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this, you have made a  function which is not called or assigned .Name the function and call it.

```js
function a(){ console.log('hi')}
a();
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using a [function expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname) in a context where the `function` keyword can only start a function declaration.

And if you want it to actually print anything: You have to **call** it.

You could make it a function declaration by giving it a name:

```js
function myFunction() {
  console.log('hi')
}

myFunction();
```

You could put it in expression context:

```js
(function() {
  console.log('hi')
})();

// or

const myFunction = function() {
  console.log('hi')
};

myFunction();

// or

+function() {
  console.log('hi')
}();

// etc
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use anonim call

```
(function(){ console.log('hi') })()
```

Answer (score 0):

add a name to your function function test() {}